# Google Drive now counts shared files against your storage?

Tags: google-drive, online-storage

I see that there is a bug or 'new feature'

A file shared with me (owned by another account) is showing

Type Image

Size 4.6 MB

Storage used 4.6 MB

Owner 'another account'

So apparently shared files now goes towards my storage or is there a bug in the information?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there has been a change to this policy

> Files Shared with You
>
> Files shared by you count against your quota. But what about files
> that someone shared with you? They don’t. So don't be concerned the
> next time someone shares a boatload of files with you.

[reference](https://www.guidingtech.com/google-drive-storage-guide-what-counts-what-doesnt/)